# Typescript correct way of setting return type on http requests

Tags: javascript, typescript

Say i have the following function:

```
getImageText(base64Image) {
    const body = {
        "requests": [
            {
                "image": {
                    "content": base64Image
                },
                "features": [
                    {
                        "type": "TEXT_DETECTION"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    };
    return this.http.post('https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=' + environment.googleCloudVisionAPIKey, body);
}
```

Now when this succeeds it returns the following: `{responses: [], text:'' }`
So in short it returns an object with a `response array` and a `text string`

Now my first attempt was to set the following return type:

```
 getImageText(base64Image): Observable<{ responses: any, text: any }>
```

However i am not sure this is the right way of doing it.

Also my console gives me an error. And what happens when this promise returns an error then the object is different.

So my question is what is the correct way of making a return type on methods that are using `http / promises`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method getImageText(base64Image) may return an Observable. However, your current implementation isn't returning one. You can convert a promise into an observable as such.

```
getImageText(base64Image): Observable<{ responses: any, text: any }>  {
    const body = {
        "requests": [
            {
                "image": {
                    "content": base64Image
                },
                "features": [
                    {
                        "type": "TEXT_DETECTION"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    };
    return from(this.http.post('https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=' + environment.googleCloudVisionAPIKey, body));
}
```

And then you can subscribeto this method where you need to.

```
function DoSomethingWithTheResponse(){
    getImageText(yourBase64Image).subscribe(
        value => {
          //do something with the value
     });
}
```